I am syed from india , bihar as my ancesstor migrate to bihar they all were sadat and the sajra which we had belongs to hussian A s , i wanna be shia?
How can i be shia , cause i an descendent from imam hussian as per sajra nama but unfortunately by father , grandfather they all follow sunni sect hanafi , but i want to be shia and a leader and scholer how can i start
